# Equivalent of “du --time -h” (or something similar) in Solaris

Tags: solaris, du

How can I get something similar to `du -h --time` at solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With Solaris 11, `/usr/gnu/bin/du -h --time`
- With older releases, the simpler would be to install gnu-coreutils from a freeware source (it might be on the Solaris companion CD).

If you want to stick with standard tools, you'll need a little bit of scripting to get a similar output.